# pyqt5: qt.qpa.xcb errors when launching app

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt4, xcb

I'm migrating my application from pyqt4 to pyqt5.
Most of it works fine except for this issue I keep having on app launch:

```
$ python3 /tmp/loading.py 
qt.qpa.xcb: failed to initialize XRandr
qt.qpa.xcb: X server does not support XInput 2
```

My application has a loading screen that I display while it loads some stuff:

```
import sys
import time

from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWidgets

from resources import Images


class LoadingScreen(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(LoadingScreen, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('Loading MyApp...')
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon(Images.LOGO))
        self.setMaximumSize(600, 338)
        self.setMinimumSize(600, 338)
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)

        self.palette = QtGui.QPalette()
        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(Images.LOADING_BACKGROUND)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(pixmap.scaled(self.size(), QtCore.Qt.IgnoreAspectRatio))
        self.palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Background, brush)
        self.setPalette(self.palette)

        center = QtWidgets.QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
        self.move(center)


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
loading_screen = LoadingScreen()
loading_screen.show()
time.sleep(5)
loading_screen.close()
```

In pyqt4 it works just fine, I see this simple loading window and then it closes.
On the hand, in pyqt5 I get the above errors in shell and the window never shows itself.

**EDIT1**

```
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
loading_screen = LoadingScreen()
loading_screen.show()
foo()
loading_screen.close()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**EDIT2**

```
import sys
import time

from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

from drivertest.ui.gui.resources.resources import Images


class Form(QtGui.QDialog):
    """ Just a simple dialog with a couple of widgets
    """
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Form, self).__init__(parent)
        self.browser = QtGui.QTextBrowser()
        self.setWindowTitle('Just a dialog')
        self.lineedit = QtGui.QLineEdit("Write something and press Enter")
        self.lineedit.selectAll()
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.browser)
        layout.addWidget(self.lineedit)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.lineedit.setFocus()

    def foo(self):
        for _ in range(100000000):
            pass


class LoadingScreen(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(LoadingScreen, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('Loading DriVerTest...')
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon(Images.LOGO))
        self.setMaximumSize(600, 338)
        self.setMinimumSize(600, 338)
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)

        self.palette = QtGui.QPalette()
        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(Images.LOADING_BACKGROUND)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(pixmap.scaled(self.size(), QtCore.Qt.IgnoreAspectRatio))
        self.palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Background, brush)
        self.setPalette(self.palette)

        center = QtGui.QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
        self.move(center)



app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
loading_screen = LoadingScreen()
loading_screen.show()

g = Form()
g.foo()

loading_screen.close()

g.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: 1) remove `time.sleep(5)`, 2) change `loading_screen.close()` to `QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(5 * 1000, loading_screen.close))` 3) add `sys.exit(app.exec_())`

Comment: The time.sleep is just to simulate the loading process. In actuality I have some method that runs. So if I change the code like it is in edit 1 it doesn't work.

Comment: @BobSacamano What exact version of Qt are you using and on which specific platform?

Comment: I'm using 5.13.0 and running over Fedora27.

Comment: @ekhumoro, see edit2. a very close approximation of my actual code. This code works fine in pyqt4. But in pyqt5 it doesn't. I see that the loading screen does open but nothing shows on the screen, and I get the errors in shell.

Comment: @BobSacamano To me, the old behaviour of qt4 seems weird, and I wouldn't rely on it. In order to display the loading screen in qt5, try calling `app.processEvents()` after `loading_screen.show()`. You might also want to consider using [QSplashScreen](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsplashscreen.html). As for the error messages: the first one may mean you're using an old xrandr (i.e. less than v1.2). Run `xrandr -v` to check. The second one may mean you're using an old xinput extension (i.e. less than v2.0). Run `xdpyinfo -ext XInputExtension | grep opcode` to check.

Comment: @ekhumoro thanks I will look into QSplashScreen.
Now, regarding the errors: 1. xrandr program version 1.5.0, Server reports RandR version 1.1. So i need to update because it is 1.1? how? 2. XInputExtension version 1.3 opcode: 131, base event: 66, base error: 129. I guess I need to update this one too. how?

Comment: @BobSacamano Fedora27 was released in Nov 2017 and reached its end of life in Dec 2018. So you are trying to use a legacy distro with the latest version of Qt5. It should therefore come as no surprise that you're seeing warning messages like this (they're not actually *errors*, as such). It ***might*** be possible to update `libxrandr` and `libXi` on your system to make these particular warnings go away. But I'm not a Fedora expert (I use Arch Linux), so I'm not entirely sure. In the long run, it would probably be better to just update to Fedora30.

Comment: @ekhumoro I did also try using fedora30 and keep getting the same warning.
qt.qpa.xcb: failed to initialize XRandr
qt.qpa.xcb: X server does not support XInput 2

Comment: @BobSacamano So what versions of `libxrandr/libXi` are being used in Fedora30? Do you get these messages when using the default Fedora Qt5 packages? If so, you should probably report it as a Fedora bug. How did you install Qt-5.13? By using unofficial packages, or by compiling it yourself?

Comment: I have the same issue with RHEL8, Qt version 5.15.2, xrandr -v
xrandr program version       1.5.0
Server reports RandR version 1.1, xdpyinfo -ext XInputExtension | grep opcode
XInputExtension version 1.3 opcode: 131, base event: 66, base error: 129. Although I did install Qt directly as a local install instead of grabbing an official RPM @BobSacamano